# Prove that $l^2$ is closed and bounded but not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the space $l^p=\{(x_i);x_i\in \mathbb C:\sum |x_i|^2<\infty\}$ .Define a norm on $l^2$ by $||x||=\sqrt{\sum |x_i|^2}$.

> Prove that $l^2$ is closed and bounded but not compact.

I know that in a finite dimensional space  a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded.But here the space is infinite dimensional;what should I do?Please give some hints.

Comment: Are you sure about this question? $l^2$ is not bounded.

Comment: I think he wants to show the closed unit ball in $\ell^{2}$ is closed and bounded but not compact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume it was compact, and derive a contradiction.   Since it's a metric space,  compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness, so all you have to do is show that you have a bounded sequence with no convergent subsequence.   When you have infinite dimensions, the usual thing to try, which works here, is just take the sequence to be each 1 in one "dimension", (here dimension in the Hilbert sense, not algebraic).

So consider the sequence ${x_n}$  where $x_ni=1$ if $n=i$ and $0$ otherwise.  It's bounded as each term has a norm of 1,  but you should be able to clearly show it doesn't converge, as it's not even cauchy (The norm of the difference of any two terms is constant!)